# Поставить switch на паузу

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, age, gender, total;

        System.out.println("Выберите пункт меню: " + "\n"
                        + "1. Указать имя " + "\n"
                        + "2. Указать возраст" +"\n"
                        + "3. Указать пол" + "\n"
                        + "4. Получить указанную вами информацию");

        int schoice = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (schoice) {
            case 1 :
                System.out.print("Введите ваше имя: ");
                name = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Спасибо, теперь мы знаем, что вас зовут " + name);
                break;
            case 2 :
                System.out.print("Введите ваш возраст: ");
                age = scanner.nextLine();
                break;
            case 3 :
                System.out.print("Укажите ва пол: " + "\n");
                System.out.println("1. Мужской" + "\n" + "2. Женский");
                gender = scanner.nextLine();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

После выбора пункта меню, например 1, ввод практически сразу закрывается и программа завершается, можно ли его "притормозить"?

Comment: Вы наверное имеете в виду поставить не на паузу, а на последующее ожидание ввода.

Comment: Немного не по теме конечно, но, можно \n использовать так:
`System.out.print("Укажите ва пол: \n");`

Comment: Если ты хочешь заполнить сразу все поля (name, age, gender, total;) то это надо делать без switch

Comment: Хотелось бы отдельно сохранять введенные данные и вывести их по 4 запросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Евгений, вот так вроде бы все работает:

```
public class ZZZZZ {
    static String name = "", age = "", gender = "", total = "";
    static boolean isFinish = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("\nВыберите пункт меню:\n"
                + "1. Указать имя\n"
                + "2. Указать возраст\n"
                + "3. Указать пол\n"
                + "4. Получить указанную вами информацию\n"
                + "5. Закончить знакомство");
            choice(scanner.nextInt());
        } while (!isFinish);
    }

    static String getUserInput() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    static void choice(int userInput) {
        switch (userInput) {
            case 1 :
                System.out.print("Введите ваше имя: ");
                name = getUserInput();
                System.out.println("Спасибо, теперь мы знаем, что вас зовут " + name);
                break;
            case 2 :
                System.out.print("Введите ваш возраст: ");
                age = getUserInput();
                System.out.println("Итак, вам " + age + " лет");
                break;
            case 3 :
                System.out.print("Укажите ва пол: " + "\n");
                System.out.println("1. Мужской" + "\n" + "2. Женский");
                gender = getUserInput();
                if (gender.equals("1")) {
                    gender = "мужчина";
                } else if (gender.equals("2")) {
                    gender = "женщина";
                }
                System.out.println("Вы " + gender + ". Отлично!");
                break;
            case 4 :
                total = name + ", " + age + " лет, " + gender;
                System.out.println("Ваши данные: " + total);
                break;
            case 5 :
                System.out.println("До свидания, " + name + "!");
                isFinish = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```